# what react native component for creating list with sub item

Tags: react-native

what react native component for creating list with sub items? I checked the docs, it could be flatlist, but flatlist doesn't say anything about sliding in sub item.

[image]

Comment: do you need something like sub listing / expandable cell ?

Comment: yea things like that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<FlatList>` for efficient displaying of a large list. This `<FlatList>` is recommended if you have a large list. Then you can contain each content of a list in `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` and provide onPress event handler.
for eg.

```
<FlatList>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={/*---include your selection logic here*/}>
        /* your content come here */
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</FlatList>
```

Also, if you want to apply animation to drop down list I would recommend you to use `<LayoutAnimation>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-collapsible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible).

it will help you to achieve same things and you can design your own styling by creating customizable view.

**Installation**

```
npm install --save react-native-collapsible
```

**Example**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react-native';
import Accordion from 'react-native-collapsible/Accordion';

const SECTIONS = [
  {
    title: 'First',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum...'
  },
  {
    title: 'Second',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum...'
  }
];

class AccordionView extends Component {
  state = {
    activeSections: []
  };

  _renderSectionTitle = section => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text>{section.content}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  _renderHeader = section => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>{section.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  _renderContent = section => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text>{section.content}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  _updateSections = activeSections => {
    this.setState({ activeSections });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Accordion
        sections={SECTIONS}
        activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
        renderSectionTitle={this._renderSectionTitle}
        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
        renderContent={this._renderContent}
        onChange={this._updateSections}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

You can customize the view by using [Properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible#properties-1)